# If I add an item to QTreeWidget it always gets inserted in first row

Tags: c++, qt

I want the new items to be inserted after the last row instead of first row.

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    QTreeWidgetItem* tempItem = new QTreeWidgetItem();
    tempItem->setText(0,QString::number(i));
    ui->treeWidget->insertTopLevelItem(tempItem,i);
}
```

It inserts the items at top, not at the bottom.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this way:

If you want to add a top level item with children:

```
//you could also create it dinamically
QTreeWidget * tree = ui->treeWidget;

QTreeWidgetItem * topLevel = new QTreeWidgetItem();
topLevel->setText(0, "This is top level");

for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    QTreeWidgetItem * item = new QTreeWidgetItem();
    item->setText(0,"item " + QString::number(i+1));
    topLevel->addChild(item);
}

tree->addTopLevelItem(topLevel);
```

Or if you want to add more top-levels:

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    QTreeWidgetItem * item = new QTreeWidgetItem();
    item->setText(0,"top-level " + QString::number(i+1));
    tree->addTopLevelItem(item);
}
```

Note, that they are in the order, they got added!

Comment: The output for this code is: 6 5 4 3 2 1 (all in different rows) but what i want is : 1 2 3 4 5 6 (all in different rows).The addTopLevelItem(item) always inserts in the first row, and not after the last row! Even if i try insertTopLevelItem(item,i), it still inserts every item in the first row, pushing previous items downwards

Comment: I don't know how you are doing it, but this is how the input should look like: [picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m9796qvt92av1jl/output.png). If it isn't, please post more code!

Comment: I tried your code, still showing in the reverse order, opposite to that shown in your image, can it be related to sorting order

Comment: Did you set the sort order? if you did, then dont expect the elements to be in the order you added them.